# How do I cast IQueryable<System.Guid> to a string?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq query and I need to get the Guid result back as a string. The following actually gives me the string representation of the object, "IQueryable". How do I go about getting the guid as a string?

Thanks!

```
  context.ApplicationId =
            DataBaseEntities.Applications.Where(a => a.Name == applicationName)
                                         .Select(a => a.Id).ToString();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're actually trying to get out a single result so what you'd need is

```
context.ApplicationId = DataBaseEntities.Applications
    .Single(a => a.Name == applicationName).Id.ToString();
```

Now if your data layer doesn't understand `Single`, you could try

```
context.ApplicationId = DataBaseEntities.Applications
    .First(a => a.Name == applicationName).Id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Well the sequence can have multiple Guids in... how do you want to join them together? For example, you could just use `string.Join` (in .NET 4; .NET 3.5 is slightly trickier):

```
string guids = DataBaseEntities.Applications
                               .Where(a => a.Name == applicationName)
                               .Select(a => a.Id);
string guid = string.Join(',', guids);
```

Or if you know there will be exactly one match, you could use `Single` to get one value, then find the Id, then call `ToString`:

```
string guid = DataBaseEntities.Applications
                              .Single(a => a.Name == applicationName)
                              .Id.ToString();
```

If there could be multiple matches, or none, you need to think about options like `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

An `IQueryable`  has many results.  You can use `.Single().ToString();` to ensure there's only one result, then convert that to a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

The queryable represents a *sequence* of `Guid` but it seems like you just want one.  So either use `First` or `Single`:

```
context.ApplicationId =  DataBaseEntities.Applications
    .Where(a => a.Name == applicationName)
    .Select(a => a.Id)
    .First()
    .ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
context.ApplicationId =
        DataBaseEntities
            .Applications
            .Where(a => a.Name == applicationName)
            .Select(a => a.Id).
            .SingleOrDefault().
            .ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your select statement is returning a list of Guid's not single Guid.  If you really just want one, you should call one of this methods:
- First(): if you you might have several, this will take the first one, and throw an error if you there are none
- FirstOrDefault(): if you might have several or none, this will take the first one, or default to an empty Guid if there is none
- Single(): if there will be exactly one, this will take that one, and will throw an exception if there are none or more than one
- SingleOrDefault(): if there will be zero or one, this will take that one, or default to an empty Guid if there is none, or will throw an exception if there are several.

```
context.ApplicationId = 
DataBaseEntities.Applications.Where(a => a.Name == applicationName)
.Select(a => a.Id).Single().ToString();
```